# Intellij -Project structure settings (spring facet config) - where are they stored?

Tags: java, spring, git, intellij-idea

Have a project that I am migrating over from netbeans to intellij.

Intellij recognises the spring config files and gives the warning "please configure/setup spring facet for modules". This requires manually adding these under project structure settings.

I don't want the other team members to all have to do this manually, so I wish to check these settings into git, but according to that, there are no changed files in the project directory (I have standard ignores added to .gitignore). I have also tried searches of file contents for the config file names etc and that turns up nothing too.

So my question is where are the settings stored? In a file that is typically on the ignored list or in a location external to the project directory?

Comment: Generally it is a bad idea to checkin IDE related files into a git/svn/cvs... Those file contain paths, not everyone has the same paths. Not everyone might want to use Intellij etc. It isn't that hard to configure the facet, it has to be done once (by a single click). Next to that what if someone has a different version, the idea files won't work between different versions.

Comment: @M.Deinum - not all IDE files contain such details, and we are standardising our environments so that is not a concern. JetBrains have guidance on which files are recommended to check into VCS ( https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/managing-projects-under-version-control.html ). And while it is easy, it is another step to forget.Time is money so spending hours working out you forgot one module is not desirable.

Comment: Unless you're not the only one in your team using IJ, I'd definitely recommend checking in the .IML files. There are many other facet settings, and Spring facet setup *can* be more than "just add all Spring config files found in one big fileset". (Disclaimer: I work on the Spring support in IJ)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially all the IDEA related configuration for the project is under .idea folder, for example, all the project workspace iteams you can find in the .idea/worksapce.xml, include the spring features you mentioned.

But this is not a good idea to keep those things in your VCs, the .idea folder is ignore default as in the configuration items will store you local env related like the full path to your local gradle, e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
  <component name="GradleSettings">
    <option name="linkedExternalProjectsSettings">
      <GradleProjectSettings>
        <option name="distributionType" value="LOCAL" />
        <option name="externalProjectPath" value="$PROJECT_DIR$" />
        <option name="gradleHome" value="C:/DevTools/gradle-2.14.1" />
        <option name="gradleJvm" value="#JAVA_HOME" />
        <option name="modules">
          <set>
            <option value="$PROJECT_DIR$" />
          </set>
        </option>
        <option name="useAutoImport" value="true" />
        <option name="myModules">
          <set>
            <option value="$PROJECT_DIR$" />
          </set>
        </option>
      </GradleProjectSettings>
    </option>
  </component>
</project>
```

Here are some files under the .idea folder for my proejct

[image]

---

Update:

For the spring facets, it's under the module .iml file, like

```
<component name="FacetManager">
    <facet type="Spring" name="Spring">
      <configuration>
        <fileset id="fileset" name="Spring Application Context" removed="false">
          <file>file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/integration-beans.xml</file>
        </fileset>
      </configuration>
    </facet>
  </component>
```

Comment: care to say which file under .idea? According to JetBrains official documentation ( https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/managing-projects-under-version-control.html ) all the .idea folder should be included apart from `tasks.xml` and `workspace.xml` for the reasons you allude to. I couldn't see it in either of them on manual inspection, and the other files should've showed up if they were modified.

Comment: @SeeMoreGain should say every project will have the `workspace.xml`, all the project worksapce configuration are in this file, and this file will keep updated once your do some configuration for your project structure, and others like add the bookmark, breakpoints......

Comment: Sorry but that is not helpful to my situation. I understand the function of workspace.xml and I have looked at the contents they do not seem to contain the spring facet linking. Where is that attribute specifically?

Comment: @SeeMoreGain sorry, update the answer, please refer to it.